# hibernate error in spring MVC.java.sql.BatchUpdateException: unique constraint (OVERFLOW.SYS_C004914) violated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I am trying  to save details of users through registration form.i am using 3 model classes one is user,roles,person.The primary key in user table is  foreign key in both roles and person tables.
I used OneToOne mapping in both roles and person.

Here is my `User` Model Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Login")
public class User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String username;
private String password;

//Rest are getters and Setters
```

My `Person` model class is

```
@Entity
public class Person{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private  int pid;
private String email;
private String Gender;
@OneToOne
private User uid;
```

My `Roles` table is

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Auth")
public class Roles implements Serializable{
@Id
private  int id;
@Column(name = "Authority")
private String role;
@OneToOne
private User u_id;
```

In my dao i am trying to insert these..

```
 public static boolean register(Person p,User u,Roles r)
 {
 Session s=sf.openSession();
 s.beginTransaction();
 s.save(u);
 s.save(p); 
 s.save(r);
 s.getTransaction().commit();
 s.flush();
 s.close();

 return true;
```

The Exception I am Getting is

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/spring7]
        threw exception [Request processing failed;
        nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
            Could not execute JDBC batch update] 
        with root cause java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: 
            unique constraint (OVERFLOW.SYS_C004914) violated

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10657)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
at com.rahul.dao.Dao.register(Dao.java:40)
at com.rahul.controller.LoginController.reg(LoginController.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: So, how is the constraint OVERFLOW.SYS_C004914 defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the inormation given i can find out below

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is missing for id field in Role entity. Though i think auto is default value.But still its worth to cross check.

As error clearly says its unique key constraint voilation. My guess is there is some check constraint defined in defined in your DB. Duplicate values are allowed for foreign keys.